# Where is the best place to get Calibre?

Tags: calibre

If you search for Calibre you find multiple places to get this free ebook management tool from.  I know some people have downloaded it and got [lots of junk at the same time](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Wikisource%3aScriptorium/Archives/2013-02#WS_to_eBook). from others, I keep hearing that this is wonderful product.

Where are the safe/reliable places to download Calibre?

Comment: Where is there the actual reference to where they got the broken calibre from? That is the first mention I have seen of malware and Calibre and I have used it for 4-5 years

Comment: @Mark if are you asking for the link William downloaded from I don't have it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The calibre home page is at [https://calibre-ebook.com](http://calibre-ebook.com) As this is open source you can see what is included in the download. The source is on [Github](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/calibre)

In general for all downloads never download from a place that lists downloads always look for the author's home page. Or you can trust places you know about by other means than a simple search.

Answer (score 6):

Newer versions of Calibre come out on a regular basis and I have not found a site from where I can automatically install the latest packages for my **Linux** system using the normal packaging download system (`apt-get`).

I therefore use a small script named `update-calibre`. It kills the currently running Calibre, moves the previous version from `/opt/calibre` (`prefix is easily changed) to a backup (`/opt/calibre-`) and then downloads and installs the latest version to`/opt/calibre` using the script provided on the calibre site specifically for [Linux installs](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux).

So whenever the calibre interface tells me there is a new version I run `update-calibre` and restart to have the latest version.

```
#!/bin/bash

# change this to your preferred install location,
# **and** update the `sudo python` line!
BASE=/opt

# make sure the server stops
killall calibre
E=$BASE/calibre/calibre
if [ -e $E ]; then
   V=$($E --version  | tr ')' ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 3  )
   sudo mv "$E" "$E-$V"
fi

sudo python -c "import sys; py3 = sys.version_info[0] > 2; u = __import__('urlli
b.request' if py3 else 'urllib', fromlist=1); exec(u.urlopen('http://status.cali
bre-ebook.com/linux_installer').read()); main(install_dir='/opt')"
```

Make sure the last line in the script corresponds to the one specified on the linux install page.

Killing the `calibre` process is necessary, as closing the interface keeps calibre running. This results in a temporarily confused user, who does not understand why the newly downloaded version number does not show up in the interface, even though the program was started.

Answer (score 5):

The calibre [download page](http://calibre-ebook.com/download) has links to instructions for all platforms that for which  downloads available:

- [Linux](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux) (detects install 32/64 bit itself)
- [OSX](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_osx)
- [Windows](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_windows)
- [Windows 64bit](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_windows64)
- [Portable Windows](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_portable)

But you might want to check these direct links for being the official download places and not another junk-yard.